# Are Acceleration Structures Mandatory for A Ray Tracing Pipeline

Tags: vulkan, raytracing

My understanding is that an acceleration structure is used as an optimization within a ray-tracing pipeline to speed up potential intersection calculations before actually needing to invoke your intersection shader. Basically, if you had a scene of some complex geometry you wrap each geometry up in an acceleration structure, then you wrap multiple of these acceleration structures together to minimize the number of geometry you actually need to test against.

If however the scene you are ray tracing against is completely dynamic and all geometry is changing locations every tick, and to go one step further, every geometry is a perfect sphere, this acceleration structure does nothing but add pointless overhead. Is it somehow possible to create a pipeline and omit the acceleration structure, or if not create a custom acceleration structure identical to the intersection shader (in the case of the perfect sphere) so that you aren't forced to use an AABB accelerator?

Comment: "*this acceleration structure does nothing but add pointless overhead.*" How do you figure that? Do you think that spheres are free to do intersection tests on? That the memory reads to load the data to test against a sphere is free? Why do you think that using spheres and dynamic geometry makes acceleration tests "pointless overhead"?

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay, thinking on this a little more, I see your point for the case of many spheres, if you're casting a million rays then it obviously makes sense to sort the spheres into this structure beforehand to reduce the number of tests to make. However what about the bottom level acceleration structure around each sphere? Surely an AABB-line intersection calculation is worse than doing a sphere-line intersection, and on top of that you need to do it twice if you're forced to wrap it in an acceleration structure

Comment: @J.Doe Does Vulkan support sphere intersections?

Comment: ... and is all your geometry really perfect spheres? They are great in principle for coarse binning (if they were supported), but at some point you need to intersect a real mesh ...

Comment: ... and you need some level of hierarchy of spheres so you don't need to do O(N) tests for every ray, which starts to sound a lot like an acceleration structure to me ...

Comment: @solidpixel right, I noted that in the previous comment about needing a top level acceleration structure, but you're still forced to wrap each sphere in a bottom level acceleration structure as well, no? Also yes, they are perfect spheres, no mesh ever.